# How can an external JavaScript determine the URL from which it was included?

Tags: javascript, script-tag

I have an external JavaScript file and I'd like to know the src attribute value URL that was used to include it in the  tag from the HTML document. For example:

`<script src='https://foo.bar/baz.js'><script>`

And then inside baz.js I'd like to write this code:

`let mysrc = getMySrc() // Should return https://foo.bar/baz.js`

Is it possible to write a getMySrc() function that does this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
const src = document.currentScript.getAttribute('src');
```

This works because `document.currentScript` will refer to the script tag corresponding to the currently running script.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @CertainPerformance. To get the resolved URL and not just what the script parameter stated:

```
const url = document.currentScript.src;
```

To get the directory where it originated:

```
let url = new URL(document.currentScript.src);
const dir = url.origin + url.pathname.replace(/\/[^\/]+$/, '/');
```